# How to get Ubuntu working from a USB?

Tags: usb, windows

I've followed the walkthrough on the Ubuntu website for installing and booting from a USB drive, however when booting I get the message:
"The selected boot device failed. Press  to Continue."

As far as I'm aware I did everything correctly, I downloaded Ubuntu from their website and installed it using Universal USB Installer - can anyone shed some light as to why it hasn't worked?

Comment: What did you use to burn Ubuntu to the USB?

Comment: I used the recommended software in the walkthrough - Universal USB Installer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that has problems on some computers. Use rufus.akeo.ie.

Comment: Yeah this worked, currently installing on my other PC now. Thankyou.

Comment: Should I add it as the answer?

Comment: Yeah feel free to.

Answer (score 0):

Universal USB Installer has problems on some computers, and doesn't always let you create a bootable drive. Use Rufus, from http://rufus.akeo.ie to make a bootable Ubuntu USB drive. It's efficient, fast, easy-to-use and free.